# Drupal Services - Checking authentication state of user

Tags: angularjs, drupal, drupal-7

I run a Angular Headless Drupal site using services module.

I have following question:
if i am logged in for a long time my session may end. 
How should i react to this and how to check if I'm still authenticated or not?

I'm also interested in handling page refresh or similar actions where authentication state should be checked.

Are there any good workflows for this?

Answer (score 1):

To check the authentication state i fire a request to system/connect. 
With token and cookie propper set this will return always the sessionis ans session_name. If you are logged in it also returns the user object of the authenticaten user. If not a anonymous user object is returned.

To handle pagerefresh and so on i end up with following workflow for:

[image]

I implemented this worflow in an AngularJS lib for Drupal Services called [ng-drupal-7-services](https://github.com/BioPhoton/ng-drupal-7-services)